# Python 3.5 Adding to dictionary and assigning a value after

Tags: python

So, I'm taking a few courses through Udemy. The final project on the Python 3.x course has you making a simple UI which I did fine.

The premise is a grade tracker for students. You could add grades, remove a student, average the student grades, and exit from the program.

I wanted to do something not in the lesson, and that was be able to add new students. I added another option. I've tried entering what I thought would work, but I keep getting errors. I could finally enter a new student, but then when I tried to add a grade for that student, it would say the student didn't exist, even though they showed up in the dictionary.

So, any clue how I can accomplish this?

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated. Code to follow:

```
    #Making a Python Program

from statistics import mean as m

admins = {'Python':'Pass123@', 'user2':'pass2'}#this will be here authorized users and passwords would be

studentDict= {'Jeff':[78,88,93],
              'Alex':[92,76,88],
              'Sam':[89, 92, 93]}

def enterGrades():
    nameToEnter= input('Student Name: ')
    gradeToEnter= input ('Grade: ')

    if nameToEnter in studentDict:
        print('Adding Grade...')
        studentDict [nameToEnter].append(float(gradeToEnter))
    else:
        print ('Student does not exist.')
    print (studentDict)

def removeStudent():
    nameToRemove = input ('Which student do you want to remove?: ')
    if nameToRemove in studentDict:
        print('Removing student...')
        del studentDict[nameToRemove]
    print (studentDict)

def addStudent():
    nameToAdd = input ('Enter the name of the new student: ')

    if nameToAdd in studentDict:
        print ('Student already exists.')
    else:
        print ('Adding new student...')
        studentDict[nameToAdd]
        print (studentDict)
        #Crashes upon entering student name.

def studentAVGs():
    for eachStudent in studentDict:
        gradeList= studentDict[eachStudent]
        avgGrade = m(gradeList)

        print(eachStudent, 'has an average grade of', avgGrade)


def main():
    print("""
    Welcome to Grade Central

    [1] - Enter Grades
    [2] - Remove Student
    [3] - Add Student
    [4] - Student Average Grades
    [5] - Exit
    """)
    action= input ('What would you like to do today? (Enter a number) ')

    if action == '1':
        enterGrades()
    elif action == '2':
        removeStudent()
    elif action == '3':
        addStudent()
    elif action == '4':
        studentAVGs()
    elif action == '5':
        exit()
    else:
        print ('No valid choice was given, try again')



login= input('Username: ')
passw= input('Password: ')

if login in admins:
    if admins[login] == passw:
        print('Welcome,',login)
        while True:
            main()
    else:
        print('Invalid Password, will detonate in 5 seconds')
else:
    print ('Invalid username, calling the FBI to report this')
```

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to enter a new student with option 3, then assign grades to that student with option 1. Do I have to enter a grade when I create a new student, so it has a value to the key right away?

Comment: Okay, poor choice of words. It's a text based program that has zero value to the real world. It's just for training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a key without a value. Also, since you expect a "student" record to be a `list`, you might as well create it with an empty list:

```
def addStudent():
    nameToAdd = input ('Enter the name of the new student: ')

    if nameToAdd in studentDict:
        print ('Student already exists.')
    else:
        print ('Adding new student...')
        studentDict[nameToAdd] = []
        print (studentDict)
```

Comment: it's a nice workaround solution, but my answer with the default dict makes it so he doesn't have to do what python already has.

Comment: @Seekheart yes indeed but since the OP is obviously not getting the basics of how a python `dict` work giving the simple answer with a `dict` is IMHO much more useful - you won't go far with Python if you don't get dicts and bindings. Actually, it's _your_ answer which is a "workaround" - it avoids the OP problem instead of solving it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a dictionary of students as keys and pointing them to a list might I suggest you take advantage of python's amazing higher order data structures? Specifically the defaultdict? As for your problem if you apply a default dict you can easily handle this problem you are having. As below.

```
from collections import defaultdict

studentDict = defaultdict(list)
#rest of your code will now work because all keys you enter in your
#addStudent() function will have an automatic value of an empty list
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful for a beginner if you explained how defaultdict works

Comment: It would also be much more helpful if it starded with the explanation of why the OP code doesn't work and how to make it work instead of provinding a magical "workaround"...